# Iterator hasnext gives second value

Tags: java, arrays, iterator

In my case I want to delete the duplicate Strings in `leveranciers` with the new HashSet `set`. 
After debugging that seems to be working but when I call `it.hasNext`..It will directly use `0230` instead of `6023`...please need some help, I'm not used to work with Iterator and HashSet.

```
String[] leveranciers = new String[wdContext.nodeShoppingCart().size()];

//Filledin leveranciers with '6023', '6023' and '0230'

//Remove duplicates from array
Set set= new HashSet(Arrays.asList(leveranciers));

for (Iterator it = set.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    PdfPTable table = GetTable(""+ it.next());
    byte[] pdf = wdThis.wdGetAchatsIndirectController().GetPDFFromFolder("/intranetdocuments/docs/AchatsIndirect", table);
    wdThis.wdGetAchatsIndirectController().PrintPDF(pdf);
}
```

Comment: you get first element as 0230 ? because there will be only two element s in set 6023 and 0230

Comment: Correct, I want as first element 6023 and in the second loop 0230

Answer (score 2):

Regarding to the fact of [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) in java that it can't contain a duplicate value, then your set values will be `6023 and 0230` only.

**Java doc:**

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at most one null element.

Answer (score 0):

From the [HashSet Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html):

> This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table (actually a HashMap instance). **It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.**

For a set, that retains the insertion order see [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)